# Why do I get InterfaceError when connecting to MySql Server in python in a docker container?

Tags: python, mysql, database, docker, database-connection

I run the code from https://github.com/aiordache/demos/tree/master/dockercon2020-demo which is from some official docker blog.

I get

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

I even tried some solutions like

```
self.cursor.execute('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%')
```

or putting in the port number:

```
    self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=user, 
            password=pf.read(),
            host=host,
            database=database,
            port='3306'
            auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )
```

I dunno whats wrong.

Comment: How are you starting the container(s)?  Do you need to wait longer for the database to come up, or to retry the connection?

Comment: I run docker-compose up -d. I think its quite fast.

Comment: If you wait 30-60 seconds, and run `docker-compose up -d` again, does it work the second time?

Comment: It says all 3 containers are up-to-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed secrets and put in the password in clear text.